# MySQL UDF Using Table Column Integer Returns Error Code: 2013

Tags: mysql, user-defined-functions

I have following query in MySQL:

```sql
SELECT FUNCTIONTEST(Column1, 27, 'SOMETHING', Column2) AS RANK1 FROM table1
```

*Column1* is varchar(100) and *Column2* is unsigned tinyint(3) with default value 0. NULL is not used.

*FUNCTIONTEST* is UDF function, which previously worked fine, but I wanted to extend it by fourth argument.

Snippet of UDF init function:

```c
bool FUNCTIONTEST_init(UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args, char *message) {
  if ((args->arg_count != 4) ||
      (args->arg_type[0] != STRING_RESULT || args->arg_type[1] != INT_RESULT || args->arg_type[2] != STRING_RESULT || args->arg_type[3] != INT_RESULT)) {
    strcpy(message, "Function requires 4 arguments, (string, int, string, int)");
    return 1;
  }
  const longlong abc = *((longlong*) args->args[1]);
  const long long def = *((long long*) args->args[3]);
```

Last line causes problems, when Column2 is used. It generates error:

> *Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query*

However, if I call query with a number directly, instead of using column, it works.

```sql
SELECT FUNCTIONTEST(Column1, 27, 'SOMETHING', 0) AS RANK1 FROM table1
```

Does anyone know, what could be the issue?

Column1, which is a string works fine (not part of snippet). I have tried to change column2 into varchar, but I am having trouble to convert string into integer in UDF. I have also tried to use *CAST* in query.

To reproduce, create following table in MySQL:

```sql
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;


CREATE TABLE `stack` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Subtract` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;

INSERT INTO `stack` (`ID`, `Name`, `Subtract`) VALUES
(1, 'Test1 Test2 Test3', 0),
(2, 'Test4 Test5 Test6', 6);

ALTER TABLE `stack`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID`);

ALTER TABLE `stack`
  MODIFY `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=3;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

UDF file called levenshtein.c:

```c
#ifdef STANDARD
/* STANDARD is defined, don't use any mysql functions */
#include <string.h>
#ifdef __WIN__
typedef unsigned __int64 ulonglong; /* Microsofts 64 bit types */
typedef __int64 longlong;
#else
#endif /*__WIN__*/
#else
//#include <my_global.h>
//#include <my_sys.h>
#if defined(MYSQL_SERVER)
#include <m_string.h>
#else
/* when compiled as standalone */
#include <string.h>
#endif
#endif

#include <mysql.h>
#include <ctype.h>
typedef unsigned long long ulonglong;
typedef long long longlong;

//#ifdef HAVE_DLOPEN

/* (Expected) maximum number of digits to return */
#define LEVENSHTEIN_MAX 3
#define INSERT_MULTIPLIER 5000
#define DELETE_MULTIPLIER 0
#define TRANSPOSITION_MULTIPLIER 2000

static inline int minimum(int a, int b, int c) {
  int min = a;
  if (b < min)
    min = b;
  if (c < min)
    min = c;
  return min;
}

#define min4(a,b,c,d) ((a)< (b) ? minimum((a),(c),(d)) : minimum((b),(c),(d)))

static inline int maximum(int a, int b) {
  if (a > b) return a;
  else return b;
}

#define min(x,y) ((x) < (y) ? (x) : (y))

bool  levenshtein2_init(UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args, char *message);
void     levenshtein2_deinit(UDF_INIT *initid);
longlong levenshtein2(UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args, char *is_null, char *error);

bool levenshtein2_init(UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args, char *message) {
  if ((args->arg_count != 4) ||
      (args->arg_type[0] != STRING_RESULT || args->arg_type[1] != INT_RESULT || args->arg_type[2] != STRING_RESULT || args->arg_type[3] != INT_RESULT)) {
    strcpy(message, "Function requires 4 arguments, (string, int, string, int)");
    return 1;
  }
  const longlong sl = *((longlong*) args->args[1]);
  const long long subtract = *((long long*) args->args[3]);
  //const long long subtract = 3;
  if (sl <= 0) {
    strcpy(message, "Argument 1 must be greater than 0");
    return 1;
  }
  if (subtract < 0) {
    strcpy(message, "Argument 3 must be greater or equal to 0");
    return 1;
  }
  if (subtract > sl) {
    strcpy(message, "Argument 3 must be lower or greater to argument 1");
    return 1;
  }

  //matrix for levenshtein calculations of size 6 x n+2 x m+2 (+1 for base values and +1 for \0)
  
  int *d = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * 6 * (args->lengths[0] + 2) * (args->lengths[2] - subtract + 2));
  if (d == NULL) {
    strcpy(message, "Failed to allocate memory");
    return 1;
  }

  initid->ptr = (char*) d;
  initid->max_length = LEVENSHTEIN_MAX;
  initid->maybe_null = 0; //doesn't return null

  return 0;
}

void levenshtein2_deinit(UDF_INIT *initid) {
  if (initid->ptr != NULL)
    free(initid->ptr);
}

longlong levenshtein2(UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args, char *is_null, char *error) {
  // Logic removed from example
  longlong bestDistance = 5;
    
  return (longlong) bestDistance;
}
```

Compiled as:

```bash
gcc -fPIC -o levenshtein.so -shared levenshtein.c `mysql_config --include`
```

Create function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION levenshtein2 RETURNS INT SONAME 'levenshtein.so';
```

Tested query:

```sql
SELECT LEVENSHTEIN2(Name, 17, 'TEST1', Subtract) AS RANK1, stack.* FROM stack
```

When commenting line 63 in levenshtein.c and uncommenting line 64, it works. It also works with line 63 and it query is executed like this:

```
SELECT LEVENSHTEIN2(Name, 17, 'TEST1', 3) AS RANK1, stack.* FROM stack
```

Comment: the fourth parameter is not mentioned in the docs, please read: [Adding a Loadable Function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/extending-mysql/8.0/en/adding-loadable-function.html), especially the chapter: "Loadable Function Argument Processing"

Comment: My bad, I meant fourth argument. All query values are part of UDF_ARGS *args. Same problem occurs, when I replace second argument with Column2

Comment: A [mre] (with full source of this UDF, and how this is used from MySQL, might be helpful. (Because I am not an expert in C, but .... ).

Comment: Post updated with reproducible example.

Comment: My guess is that this is because you're not specifying the expected type of the arguments in your `levenshtein2_init` function, as the documentation states you must. The argument type validation that you have in your `levenshtein2_init` function belongs in your `levenshtein2` function. [Please read and follow the documentation properly before posting a question here.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/extending-mysql/8.0/en/adding-loadable-function.html#loadable-function-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

My current workaround is not validating and using value of the fourth argument in the init function, which means that I am allocating more memory than I need, but I am OK with that as it does not differ from my previous usage of this function.

```
bool levenshtein2_init(UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args, char *message) {
  if ((args->arg_count != 4) ||
      (args->arg_type[0] != STRING_RESULT || args->arg_type[1] != INT_RESULT || args->arg_type[2] != STRING_RESULT || args->arg_type[3] != INT_RESULT)) {
    strcpy(message, "Function requires 4 arguments, (string, int, string, int)");
    return 1;
  }
  const longlong sl = *((longlong*) args->args[1]);
  //const long long subtract = *((long long*) args->args[3]);
  if (sl <= 0) {
    strcpy(message, "Argument 1 must be greater than 0");
    return 1;
  }

  //matrix for levenshtein calculations of size 6 x n+2 x m+2 (+1 for base values and +1 for \0)
  
  int *d = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * 6 * (args->lengths[0] + 2) * (args->lengths[2] + 2));
  if (d == NULL) {
    strcpy(message, "Failed to allocate memory");
    return 1;
  }

  initid->ptr = (char*) d;
  initid->max_length = LEVENSHTEIN_MAX;
  initid->maybe_null = 0; //does not return null

  return 0;
}

longlong levenshtein2(UDF_INIT *initid, UDF_ARGS *args, char *is_null, char *error) {
  longlong subtract = *((longlong*) args->args[3]);
  if (subtract < 0) {
    subtract = 0;
  }
  int sl = *((int*) args->args[1]);
  if (subtract > sl) {
    subtract = 0;
  }
  
  // Logic removed from example
  longlong bestDistance = subtract;
    
  return (longlong) bestDistance;
}
```

I still do not understand, why `longlong subtract = *((longlong*) args->args[3]);` does not work in the init function. Clearly, result from DB is integer and casting is done per documentation. It works in the main function.

If wrong argument value is provided, I change *subtract* variable to 0 instead of failing the function.

Comment: You still haven't followed the documentation as instructed, of course your code is not going to work correctly.